# Fastest Way To Create 1 Million Files In Java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to create 1 million files containing records in it and insert it in Oracle DB using Java Code.

```
System Configuration is :
  RAM:-32GB
  HDD:-100GB
  Processor:-Intel Core 2 Duo
```

What would be the best approach.

Approach I am planing to follow is  :

1. Since I have good amount of RAM, I will create 100 files using Thread Pool Executer with pool size of 5 (20 files per thread) and each thread will again call another thread pool which will execute 5 thread (1 file each thread) to insert the data in DB. Once data is inserted in the DB old files will deleted and new bunch of 100 files will be create and so on. I also have to query DB at levels when certain amount of data (100, 1000, 10000, 10000 up to 1 million) has been inserted in DB.
2. Create dump files for each (100, 1000, 10000, 10000 up to 1 million) and restore one by one and query to get the result (Do I need to restart the application to restore dump 2 or more files or It will just work fine no matter I restore any number of dump files in DB without restarting the application server).
3. Create zip files for each (100, 1000, 10000, 10000 up to 1 million) extract it when needed and read files from location and insert in DB using 5 or more thread pools.

Is this a right approach or is there a better way to do this? Please suggest...

Any idea how may threads I will be able to run simultaneously if I have 32GB of RAM ?

Comment: Additionally, you may want to consider explicitly creating temporary files for this.

Comment: Yes, Creating temp files I have already considered.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on the file system you'd have to split that million into smaller chunks (subdirectories etc.) since some only support a limited amount of entried (files, links, subdirectories) per directory.

Comment: @Thomas That's why I am creating only 100 files at a time deleting it before creating another bunch if 100 files.

Comment: Hmm I might have misunderstood "100, 1000, 10000, 10000 up to 1 million" then. But good that you know and keep it in mind :)

Comment: @Thomas What approach do you think is best out of the three mentioned above ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure I even understand the requirement. Why do you need to create 1 million files instead of just a few? What would those records contain, how big and complex could they get? Where does the data come from and where will it go?